# How to get time elapsed from a gmt date to now?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a date in this format

```
Fri Mar 22 2013 23:38:20 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

I must detect how much time it's elapsed since the date to now

I've availability of pre javascript and jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](http://jsbin.com/omahay/3/edit) :

```
 function secondsToString(seconds)
    {
    var numyears = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
    var numdays = Math.floor((seconds % 31536000) / 86400); 
    var numhours = Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600);
    var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
    return numyears + " years " +  numdays + " days " + numhours + " hours " + numminutes + " minutes " + numseconds + " seconds";

    }


    var t1=  Date.parse('Fri Mar 22 2013 23:38:20 GMT+0100 (CET)');
    var t2=  new Date()

    alert(secondsToString((t2-t1)/1000)) //"0 years 0 days 9 hours 39 minutes 40.98599999999715 seconds"
```

Comment: Wow ! I can subtract two date ... I didn't know !

Comment: yup. please notice the result is in ms.